# Replace broken tile with concrete

Tags: bathroom, concrete, tile, vinyl-flooring

I have an 2nd-story bathroom with a concrete tile floor. This was built in the 1950s, so it's plywood subfloor with about an inch of concrete in metal mesh, then tile on top of that. The mosaic tile has broken near the tub (approx 4"x12"), and I cannot afford to rip out all the tile and replace. There are also tiles on the wall that go all the way down to the floor and they would probably incur some damage going that route.

I am considering digging out all the broken tile, and then filling the cavity with fresh concrete. After curing, I would cover the entire floor with a sheet vinyl product. Is there anything else I could do to repair this broken area aside from just overhauling the entire bathroom?

For the record, all the contractors I have spoken with have told me I will have to rip up the floor ($$) and since they can't do that without hurting the tile on the walls, I will need to redo that as well ($$$).

Comment: Anything else you could do... to accomplish what? It's not clear what you're asking. Have you found matching or coordinating tile?

Comment: Anything else I could do to repair the broken area of tile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First that concrete subfloor you have is great.  Don't ever demo a good concrete bathroom subfloor unless you have to.

Second if you don't want a tile floor it is very easy to demo the tile without hurting the concrete sub - [How can I speed up the removal of stubborn tile?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/63786/how-can-i-speed-up-the-removal-of-stubborn-tile/63792#63792)

Third - an easier more viable option is to take out an area of tile around tub including your broken tile and find complementary tile.  Since it is by the tub it is very conceivable that there could be accent tile there.  This would probably be $30-50 and a couple hours of work.