# How can I remove tile from a floor?

Tags: tile, mold, adhesive, removal

[image: second pic][image: pic of floor][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYETC.jpg)So I decided to remove old gross carpet from a bedroom we haven't used yet so I can start using it and discovered that there was a lot of black mold under it. I am assuming previous people either had a leak or spilled water and didn't deal with it. Under the carpet is old cracked tile flooring, so I decided to remove that because that is where the mold is. Problem is it's so stuck to the floor took me half hour to get 6 tiles off.

I used a chisel and tried to get under the tile. I also tried heating them up with an iron. left it there for 3 minutes, didnt help. Some broke and came off in bits. These are thick tiles, not sure what they are made of, but they don't seem to be peel and stick because there is a lot of glue under there. Most of the tiled are cracked. I am wearing gloves and face mask. there must be a better way so I am not here doing this for months.

Comment: What is the type of subflooring your are dealing with?  Wood planks, plywood, concrete?

Comment: Do any of the [many existing questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adiy.stackexchange.com+remove+ceramic+tile) answer your question? In particular, I'd look at [How can I speed up the removal of stubborn tile?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/63786/35141)

Comment: sorry yes it is plywood

Answer (score 1):

With a plywood subfloor, it is a dirty, tiring, time consuming job to chisel all the tile off the floor.  Then you have horribly damaged plywood that may have to be removed as well if not at least covered over with another thin layer.

Do yourself a favor and consider covering the tile with a solid core vinyl product like LVP or LVT.

You may only need to clean the mildew from a small area and pour some leveling compound to even out the area you already removed tiles.

This would be less time, less money.

Update:  Since the pictures have been posted, it may be an old tile that contained asbestos.  Have it tested first.  The result will determine the next course of action.

Comment: and i can put this over the mold? the whole thing is pretty much moldy, very little area is not

Comment: No you can't.  However it is highly unusual for tile to be moldy unless it is a natural stone like marble.  The grout can be moldy, but that can be cleaned.  Pics of what you have would be very helpful.

Comment: I added a pic to my main question, just not sure if you can see it?

Comment: I was under the impression the tile was ceramic.  A picture changes everything.  That could be an old tile that contains asbestos.  Only a lab test will confirm that.  Be careful. You may want to get a home test kit.  This changes everything.

Comment: And if there are any exterior walls bordering this plywood, then there's a good chance that it's important to maintain continuity of the interior plywood with the bit of plywood that's sandwiched between bottom plate and rim joist. Damaging that plywood could be a disaster. The asbestos potential signals entombing as the solution, too.

Comment: oh crap.. i really hope not, as I remived 12 tiles. and they fell apart.. I have shut the door to that room, and i guess i should shut the window as I opened for air.. I will see where I can find a test kit tomorrow.. and I did not put that ceramic in the header, I am not sure how that happened.. I changed the heading and took that out..  thanks for the help i will post after I tested the tiles

Comment: I cannot find test kits in canada,  everything I have found says to hire someone to come check?

Comment: ok I am just going to assume its asbestos because I did a search and now pretty sure that is what it is. and now I have disturbed it.. what should I do now? can I cover this stuff with something?

Comment: You may want to call a company that does asbestos remediation.

Comment: ok thank you RMDman, thanks for all your help, greatly appreciated